# Is there anything special about components integration within Jhipster project?

Tags: angular, jhipster, angular-components

I am trying to integrate the FullCalendar component to my Jhipster Project, but it doesn't work.
Is there any steps out of the ones specified in the link below: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ap-angular2-fullcalendar.
My page is displayed but not my calendar. When i do F12, no error is displayed. So i don't know what to do to understand where is my error.

I think that my error is in my component integration. Is there anything special about component integration within a Jhispter project?

PS: I also tried to integrate the FullCalendar component in a brand new non-Jhipster project and I worked. So it is only within a Jhipster project that it causes some issues.

PS: sorry for my English.

app.module.ts:

```
enter code here
//all imports are here ...
//IMPORTS FOR MY CALENDAR
import {CalendarComponent} from "ap-angular2-fullcalendar";
import { MonCalendrierComponent } from './monCalendrier/monCalendrier.component';

import {
    JhiMainComponent,
    LayoutRoutingModule,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ProfileService,
    PageRibbonComponent,
    ActiveMenuDirective,
    ErrorComponent
} from './layouts';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        LayoutRoutingModule,
        Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: 'jhi', separator: '-'}),
        ProgestoSharedModule,
        ProgestoHomeModule,
        ProgestoAdminModule,
        ProgestoAccountModule,
        ProgestoEntityModule
        // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
    ],
    declarations: [
        JhiMainComponent,
        NavbarComponent,
        ErrorComponent,
        PageRibbonComponent,
        ActiveMenuDirective,
        FooterComponent,
        CalendarComponent,
        MonCalendrierComponent,
        ComposantTestComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        ProfileService,
        customHttpProvider(),
        PaginationConfig,
        UserRouteAccessService
    ],
    bootstrap: [ JhiMainComponent ]
})
export class ProgestoAppModule {}
```

monCalendrier.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-mon-calendrier',
  templateUrl: 'monCalendrier.component.html'
})
export class MonCalendrierComponent {

  calendarOptions:Object = {
        //height: 'parent',tohHeroButto
        fixedWeekCount : false,
        defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
          {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2016-09-01'
          },
          {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2016-09-07',
            end: '2016-09-10'
          },
          {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2016-09-09T16:00:00'
          },
          {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2016-09-16T16:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2016-09-11',
            end: '2016-09OCEANEDM-13'
          },
          {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2016-09-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2016-09-12T12:30:00'
          },<jhi-mon-calendrier></jhi-mon-calendrier>
          {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2016-09-12T12:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2016-09-12T14:30:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Happy Hour',
            start: '2016-09-12T17:30:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Dinner',
            start: '2016-09-12T20:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2016-09-13T07:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2016-09-28'
          }
        ]
      };

    constructor() {
        console.log("AA BB");    
    }

}
```

home.component.html:

```
<jhi-mon-calendrier></jhi-mon-calendrier>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import the calendar in your module like this :

```
import {CalendarComponent} from "ap-angular2-fullcalendar";

import {
    ...
    CalendarComponent
} from './layouts';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        CalendarComponent
    ],
    ...)
```